# add `movieclip` from external swf's library

Tags: actionscript-3

I loaded External `swf` file to stage :

```
var mcLoader = new Loader();
this.addChild(mcLoader);

mcLoader.load(new URLRequest("E:\\MySWF.swf"));
var mcLoader = new Loader();
this.addChild(mcLoader);
```

now I want to add a `movieclip` from external swf's library with "Part3" as linkage name, I did like below :

```
var cls:Class = mcLoader.contentLoaderInfo.applicationDomain.getDefinition("Part3") as Class;
var MCCurrentPart = new cls;
```

but it didn't work, After that I tried like this :

```
var MCCurrentPart = new mcLoader.content.Part2;
```

but now it gives error : Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of `getDefinition()` is fine, just you have to wait until the `Event.COMPLETE` event in the `contentLoaderInfo` of the `Loader` is fired.

So you can do like this :

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, on_content_load);
    loader.load(new URLRequest('swf.swf'));

function on_content_load(e:Event): void 
{
    var MyClass:Class = loader.contentLoaderInfo.applicationDomain.getDefinition('MyClass') as Class;
    var obj = new MyClass;
    addChild(obj);
}
```

You can take a look in some examples from Adobe [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/ApplicationDomain.html#includeExamplesSummary).

Hope that can help.